# Get timestamp object witth hour and minutes at midnight

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

My question is how to get timestamp in python of current date, but with the hour and minute part at midnight. as for example in today's timestamp  `11/12/2020 @ 12:00am (UTC)` and not at some other hour like in `11/12/2020 @ 10:46pm (UTC)`. I tried the `datetime` lib. but I could not do it.

Comment: While your question is not clear, are you looking for `datetime.date.today()`?

Comment: I need a timestamp not date.

Comment: Please edit your question and remove ambiguity, you say that you need *something*, not *something* (!?). Add an example of what format you want for the timestamp.

Comment: Do you want a string or a timestamp object?

Comment: I already did that in a question. First is timestamp from 11/12 in 12.00 AM, means its first timestamp in a day, second is based on actual hour.

Comment: Do you mean you want your current time in UTC, without the difference for your timezone?

Comment: I mean i want exact timestamp form 12am excluding hours.

Comment: Edited the post to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the date you can stick to datetime.

```py
from datetime import date
date_today = date.today()
#datetime.date(2020, 11, 12)
```

Edit:
to get a timestamp

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
datetime.fromisoformat(str(date.today()))
#datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 12, 0, 0)
```

Comment: I already tried this, but i need a timestamp not a date. If i use datetime.timestamp it says that the format is wrong.

Comment: Maybe use this `datetime.fromisoformat(str(date.today()))` this will create an datetime object like `datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 12, 0, 0)` if you need timezone information add the timezone with pytz

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted. Thank you !

Comment: @BartoszBicki OK, I got what you wanted.